# Form handling in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, intellij-idea

Been learning Node.js so far, building some MVC application but still cannot handle form properly, and I need some help to figure out how things work.

Okay, the best way to figure how this thing works is on my previous question, Steam Web API programming.

I installed express and steamwebapi. My **index.html** is looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Steam</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/ask_user_id" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="id"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Pošalji">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My **app.js**:

```
    //Express
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

//Steam
var SteamWebAPI = require('steamwebapi').SteamWebAPI;
SteamWebAPI.setAPIKey('xxx key is here ');

//Rendering form in index.html file
server.get('/ask_user_id', function(req, res) {
    app.render('form', function(err, html) {
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        else
            return res.send(html)
    });
});

//Route for handling form submission
server.post('/user_infos', function(req, res) {
    //Form submitted in req.body, retriving userID

    var _userID = req.body.userId;

    //SteamWebAPI - getRecentlyPlayedGames
    SteamWebAPI.getRecentlyPlayedGames(_userID, 5, function(response) {
        return res.json(response.response.games);
    });
});

//Localhost
server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server: 3000');
});
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. I type in terminal Node App.js, server:3000. If I go to my index.html file, it redirected me to http://localhost:63342/Steam/index.html, and if I type something in form, it redirect me to: http://localhost:63342/ask_user_id and I got "404 Not Found".

What I'm doing wrong? If I type node app.js and then go to localhost:3000/ask_user_id I got reference error. Someone once asked me why I need app there; I don't know, if I put server it results in an error again.

Comment: No offense, but you should work through one of the many online Node.js tutorials if you don't know what you're doing. Then, work Steam into it once its working.

Comment: Of course, I got myself a book, Web development with Node.js and Express, but how can I learn if I don't practice? I learned alot these few weeks, but this is essential thing, nothing too hard obviously...or im wrong 'bout it

Comment: thats good you got a book. what I am saying is you can find many tutorials (i'm sure there is a section in your book) that go through how to set up a form. At this point though, there is no point in adding complexity by integrating Steam API.

Comment: I can handle form but cannot do it with steam api...

Comment: in your html, change to `action="/user_infos"`

Comment: Going to: http://localhost:3000/user_infos, I get error: Cannot GET /user_infos

Going to: http://localhost:63342/Steam/index.html, I get again: 404 Not Found

Comment: you should not be able to GET /user_infos. They way forms work online (hence me recommending a tutorial) is that often you POST data to a url, but you cannot visit it directly

Comment: Ik, I got: server.get('/ask_user_id'...) and server.post('/user_infos'...)

Comment: right, so that means when you try and visit `localhost:300/user_infos` (this performs a GET), there is nothing for you to get

Comment: So, I'm supposed to POST that or GET?

Comment: visiting a URL and seeing an HTML page is a GET. submitting a form is a POST. so you GET `/ask_user_id` and you POST your data to `/user_infos`

Comment: That's how my code looks...?

Comment: right. so what I am saying is you are getting the proper behaviour. `localhost:63342/Steam/index.html` is not defined anywhere that I see so you get a 404. `localhost:3000/user_infos' is defined as a POST for form submission, so you cannot GET it by visiting directly, and `localhost:3000/ask_user_id` displays your form because it is defined as a GET.

Comment: I'm super thankful for your help but I'm kinda confused now, I'm still newbie, I'm sorry for being dumb. >.> Basically, going to:
http://localhost:3000/user_infos, I get Cannot GET /user_infos error, that is form submission post but..what's wrong here :( :( God bless you...but im dumb XD

Comment: the error is good. you should not be able to go to `localhost:3000/user_infos`. you should only be able to POST data to it by submitting your form

Comment: Oh, I'm kinda getting it. But, how do I submit my form, a.k.a POST data?

Comment: click the submit button! the form and browser will do it for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: app is not definied in Node.js - SteamWebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736053/referenceerror-app-is-not-definied-in-node-js-steamwebapi)

Comment: I don't understand you. Can you help me or...? I'm looking way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

in your html, change to `action="/user_infos"`

the request will go like this

```
GET /ask_user_id   <- this is you going to localhost:3000/ask_user_id in browser
POST /user_infos   <- this is you submitting the data to the URL specified in the action attribute of your form.
```

Comment: Now I'm getting error: ReferenceError: app is not defined... :(

Comment: update your question with the current code you are running

Comment: on line 11 of `app.js` you call `app.render()`. it should be `server.render()` since that is what you called you express app on line 3: `var server = express();`

Comment: Umm, I was doing that but I got strange error: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.?
What this means?

Comment: so express is usually used with a templating engine, not just straight html. google EJS. It lets you stick data in your html, but it will also just let you enter regular html

Comment: when you call `server.render()`, it tries to use the templating engine to render your html. except since you have not told it to use one, it breaks. setting up EJS is simple and should get you up and running

Comment: if you are still having trouble, update your question with your current code and I am happy to keep helping

Comment: I'm so glad you're so kind! I've installed it in my terminal, error is still same. Do I need to require something, make any changes? Sorry for bothering pal :'(

Comment: no problem. did you add `server.set('view engine', 'ejs');` to app.js?

Comment: uh oh, something worked out!!!!, finally not error XD

what is this: {"view":{"defaultEngine":"ejs","ext":".ejs","name":"form","root":"C:\\Users\\Benjamin Kljuno\\Documents\\Projekti\\Node.js\\Projekti\\views"}}

Comment: where are you seeing this? also, you will have to change index.html to index.ejs

Comment: Going to: http://localhost:3000/ask_user_id, I get that. How can I edit? I mean, then I get, index.ejs.html, cannot change only to .ejs...

Comment: you can normally highlight the entire filename with the mouse and edit

Comment: I haven't installed plugin in IntelliJ IDEA, that's why I could not edit it. I've edited, but still got same 'error'.

Comment: is your index.ejs inside a folder called "views"?

Comment: also, I would ditch the IDE until you know what you are doing. It is better if you understand what is going on without it. you don't need a plugin

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK. It was not, I'm gonna put it now!

index.ejs is in folder views, but why?
app.js is outside all folders

still same error

Comment: eh, I tried. please go through a simple tutorial on express. If you can't get your html page to display, then that is a whole other issue. The changes you made earlier should resolve your original problem, but I'm not going to walk you through setting up express. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, gonna look up somewhere else! Once again, you helped me alot, all the best pal

Answer (score 0):

the post actio in client is "ask_user_id"

change the server to listen

server.post('/ask_user_id',

no server.get

Comment: If I enter my Steam ID in form in this case: '76561198190043289', I once again get error: 404 Not Found, url is still: http://localhost:63342/ask_user_id,

but if I go to: localhost:3000/ask_user_id, I'm getting: Cannot GET /ask_user_id